# Ajuste de modelos exponenciales para ensayo factorial

Tags: r

Tengo un diseño experimental factorial 3x3 y deseo realizar una regresión no lineal para ajustar exponencialmente con todos los factores.
Cuando quiero ajustar el modelo en 3d, observo que si fijo cualquiera de los factores (sea Nurea o NCP) el resto de los datos se ajusta en un plano como una exponencial, por lo que deseo ajustar el modelo a una "exponencial en el espacio o en 3d", pero necesito una fórmula para poder realizarlo la cual desconozco. Actualmente ajusto los puntos a un plano de la siguiente forma:

```
LmP<-lm(P ~ NM + NCP, data=S)
summary(LmP)

set.seed(700)
Pg <- as.data.frame(cbind(NM=sample(1:100, 100),
                            NCP=sample(1:100, 100),
                            P=sample(1:100, 100)))

newdataP <- expand.grid(NM=seq(min(S$NM),max(S$NM),by=5), 
                         NCP=seq(min(S$NCP),max(S$NCP),by=5))


newdataP$P_predicted_vals <- predict(LmP,newdata=newdataP)
View (newdataP)
with(S,plot3d(NM, NCP, P, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z", col="blue", size=1, type="s", box = FALSE, axes = TRUE))

with(newdataP,surface3d(unique(NM),unique(NCP),P_predicted_vals,
                         alpha=0.3,front="line", back="line"))
```

Para realizar todo esto uso las librerías:

```
library(mosaic)
library(ggplot2)
library(nlstools)
library(minpack.lm)
library(qpcR)
library(broom)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
```

Aquí les dejo una muestra de los datos:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvg26kaihxgg9rd/S.xlsx?dl=0
Gracias!